# How do you replace factorial, nCr and nPr operations in python?

Tags: python, math, replace

I want that whenever:

I write '!' it changes the symbol to 'math.factorial'

When I write `C` it does the choose (`nCr`) operation (`n! / (r! (n - r)! )`)

If I write `P` it does the permutation (`nPr`) operation (`n! / (n - r)!`)

This is the code I started to write:

```
import math
term = ['math.factorial']
replace = ['!']
a = input('')
for word in replace:
    a = a.replace(word, term[replace.index(word)])

print(a)
```

This piece of code will change '!' to 'math.factorial' so that I will be able to calculate with the factorial operation.
However, I would like to be able to move 'math.factorial' before the number.

Ex.

This is what my program does:

If I input `2*x + (9-5)!`

My program will print `2*x + (9-5)math.factorial`

Ex.

It should do:

If I input `2*x + (9-5)!`

My program will print `2*x + math.factorial(9-5)`

And this should also be done with both the `nCr` and `nPr` operation.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your question needs to be clearer but as best I can understand it you want to parse simple arithmetic expressions that may also include a postfix factorial operator. Well, that's not trivial. You can search the web for 'parsing simple expressions' to get a decent start. In the meantime please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import re

input_line = "2*x + (9-5)! + 99! + max! + (x-3)! -4"

pattern = "\(.+?\)(?=!)|[0-9]+(?=!)|[a-z]+(?=!)"
result = re.findall(pattern, input_line)
print(result)
output_line = input_line
for match in result:
    if match[0] == '(':
        output_line = output_line.replace(f"{match}!", f"math.factorial{match}")
    else:
        output_line = output_line.replace(f"{match}!", f"math.factorial({match})")

print(output_line)
```

It first creates a regular expression `"\(.*?\)(?=!)| [0-9]*(?=!)| [a-z]*(?=!)"`
which is then matched against the input line. All matches are stored in `result`.

You then replace all matches in the input line with the desired part.
Running this will produce the output:

```
2*x + math.factorial(9-5) + math.factorial(99) + math.factorial(max) + math.factorial(x-3) -4
```

You can do it a similar way for other operators.

EDIT: I could not stop myself from trying more. 
This gets closer to a good solution, but still has flaws.

```
import re

input_line = "2*x + (9-5)! + 99! + max! + (x-3)! -4 * ((7 + 2!)!)"
pattern_1 = "[0-9]+(?=!)"
pattern_2 = "[a-z]+(?=!)"
pattern_3 = "\(.+?\)(?=!)"
result_1 = re.findall(pattern_1, input_line)

output_line = input_line
result_3 = re.findall(pattern_3, output_line)

for match in result_3:
    output_line = output_line.replace(f"{match}!", f"math.factorial{match}")
for match in result_1:
    output_line = output_line.replace(f"{match}!", f"math.factorial({match})")
result_2 = re.findall(pattern_2, input_line)
for match in result_2:
    output_line = output_line.replace(f"{match}!", f"math.factorial({match})")
result_3 = re.findall(pattern_3, output_line)

print(output_line)
```

It creates the output:

```
2*x + math.factorial(9-5) + math.factorial(99) + math.factorial(max) + math.factorial(x-3) -4 * math.factorial((7 + math.factorial(2)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works most of the times. However if I input: 5 + 9! - x + 9! + (7 + 2!)! it forgets to convert '+ 2!'  to:  '+ math.factorial(2). For the rest, it's great

Comment: It should be possible to handle this by a loop checking if there is a `!` left. If so, it applies the patterns again and replace them again.

Comment: Thank you! That's great!

Comment: Could you tell me where you've encountered flaws?

Comment: Sow I found one; maybe you can help me. Just if you want (you've done a lot of work). So when I input: math.sqrt((5+9!)!); it will output: math.sqrtmath.factorial((5+math.factorial(9))); how do you put the first 'math.factorial between the first 2 parentheses? So the output will be: math.sqrt(math.factorial(5+math.factorial(9)))

Comment: There are issues when you enter formulae like 
`((x+y!)!)!` or `(x+y!)!!`. It then ignores the last `!`. 
This may be solved by adding a loop again. But then you are going to run into the problem you described, sooner or later. 

What also disturbs my peace of mind is, that like that it is impossible to check if the formula is syntactically correct. 
While it might be possible to solve this thing by regular expressions only, I would suggest another approach.

Comment: Did you ever hear of deterministic finite automata? We could design one that accepts exactly all well formed
formulae. This would mean to disassemble the formula entered, replace the parts you want to replace and then 
reassemble it. 
I did something similar for formulae of temporal logic. If you may restrict the syntax to formulae where 
every two numbers or variables, separated by an operator are in between parentheses (e.g. `((x+y)+z)` is allowed, while `x+y+z` is not)
it is fairly easy to build a binary parse tree. With that you may compute the result as well do all the replacements.

Comment: For information about dfa [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton](see here).
For information about parse trees [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree](see here)

Comment: I prepared a repo with a program that I wrote a while ago to parse formulae of propositional logic https://github.com/CodingClownsGitHouse/PropParser . Feel free to check it out. It contains building the parse tree and can be extended to evaluating it pretty easily. Feel free to ask, if you get stuck.